Inferring a type
I'm revisiting an issue after a year of being stumped by it. I have no idea how to frame this question concisely so please bare with me.
ISSUE: I want to narrow the union type of a nested object by the value of its kind property. However, the kind field is optional because it should be "string" by default.
The TField type (simplified):
type TField = {
  field: string;
  name: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  required?: boolean;
}& (
  | { kind: "string"; value?: string; block?: boolean }
  | { kind: "password"; value?: string }
  | { kind: "email"; value?: string }
  | { kind: "number"; value?: number }
  | { kind: "boolean"; value?: boolean; inline?: boolean; toggle?: boolean }
)

// ----- EDIT: I want the "name","field","kind" to be optional
// ----------- By default: "kind" should be 'string'

type PartialBy<T,K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Partial<Pick<T, K>>
type TLabeledField = PartialBy<TField, "name"|"field"|"kind">

type TFieldCluster = {
    [key: string]: TLabeledField;
  };

function makeFields(cluster: TFieldCluster){
  const fieldMap = Object.entries(cluster).map(([str, path]) => {
    let label = str;
    let name,field;
    let required = false;

    if (label.endsWith("*")) {
      required = true
      label = label.slice(0,-1)
    }
    if (label.startsWith("$")){
      field = label.slice(1);
      name = label.replace(/([A-Z])/g, " $1").toLowerCase();
    } else {
      field = label // <-- will fix
      name = label
    }
    

    return [
      field,
      {
        type: "string",
        name,
        field,
        required,
        ...path,
      },
    ];
  });
  return Object.fromEntries(fieldMap);
}

const fields = makeFields({
      title: {},
      subtitle: {kind:"boolean", toggle: true}, // <-- SHOULD BE VALID BECAUSE I SPECIFIED 'KIND'
      about: { block: true },
      count: { kind:"number", block: true }, // <-- INVALID: 'BLOCK' ISN'T ON NUMBER!
})


Please [edit] to make the code a [mre] where the only problems present are the ones you're asking about. We don't have types like validatorFn or values like parseLabel or genFields or isEntry so our IDEs will just complain about that, which is, at best, a distraction. Please [edit] to either replace with built-in types, or give us a definition for these values and types (and, if so, please use conventional UpperCamelCase names for types to distinguish them from values). Also,name and field will be overwritten in that spread, which is a TS error you're not asking about. Please fix.

If I try to fix all the stuff I mentioned, I get the code in this playground link and... what's the issue? Where is the problem, exactly? I must be missing it.

I appreciate the effort. I will revise the original question with more specificity. I found that Typescript can narrow down the type when it gets the correct TField value. The problem occurs when I make the “kind” field optional and I’m having trouble writing the code that makes it default to a “string”-type TField by default. I’ll add all of this to the original question also.

I stripped a lot of code away to make it more concise. I missed a couple of spots.

I strongly suggest you put your code into an IDE to see what happens. When I do that I see errors you're not asking about, and there's no indication in the code itself what the problem is. It should jump right out at us. Saying "I'm having trouble writing the code" in a comment doesn't help me... where in the code specifically is that trouble manifested? This isn't a [mre] and I don't know how to proceed without one. Could you please [edit] the code so that it makes the problem clear?

Tested in playground and am getting the specific errors that I'm dealing with locally. Fixed the original post.

With the new version, your issue is mostly with PartialBy<T, K> not being distributive over unions in T. If I fix that as shown in this playground link then it works as expected according to your example. Does this fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

I could cry. Yes, that appears to be the solution. Thank you.

Happy cry or sad cry? I'll write up an answer soon. Please know that I'm taking "yes, that appears to be the solution" as confirmation that if I write up an answer you won't say "actually there's more to it" or something like that (I mean, without opening a new question post)

Happy cry lol. And no, this solves the issue of the compiler not correctly narrowing the signature. Did a cursory test locally, but that's enough for me. I appreciate your patience

The core of the issue is that, as written,
type PartialBy<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Partial<Pick<T, K>>

does not distribute over unions in T.  You clearly intend that PartialBy<T1 | T2 | T3, K> will evaluate to PartialBy<T1, K> | PartialBy<T2, K> | PartialBy<T3, K>. But it doesn't. Neither the Pick nor the Omit utility types distribute over unions. (See Why doesn't discriminated union work when I omit/require props?) Instead they act on unions at once, collapsing them to single object types:
That means
type TLabeledField = PartialBy<TField, "name" | "field" | "kind">

evaluates to
type TLabeledField = Omit<TField, "name" | "field" | "kind"> &
  Partial<Pick<TField, "name" | "field" | "kind">>

which is equivalent to
type TLabeledField = {
    placeholder?: string;
    required?: boolean;
    value?: string | number | boolean;
    name?: string;
    field?: string;
    kind?: "string" | "number" | "boolean" | "password" | "email";
}

and that's not how you want TLabeledField to behave.

You can take any generic type and make it distribute over the type parameter by wrapping it in a distributive conditional type.  If NonDistrib<T> is not distributive, you can write type Distrib<T> = T extends unknown ? NonDistrib<T> : never.  You're not really trying to check T extends unknown (the intent is that it should always be true, and so you can also write T extends any or T extends T or something else always true). It's just that doing so makes the type distributive.
That gives you
type PartialBy<T, K extends keyof T> = T extends unknown ?
    Omit<T, K> & Partial<Pick<T, K>> :
    never;

And now
type TLabeledField = PartialBy<TField, "name" | "field" | "kind">

evaluates to
type TLabeledField = (Omit<{
    field: string; name: string;
    placeholder?: string; required?: boolean;
} & {
    kind: "string"; value?: string; block?: boolean;
}, "name" | "field" | "kind"> & Partial<Pick<{
    field: string; name: string;
    placeholder?: string; required?: boolean;
} & {  
    kind: "string"; value?: string; block?: boolean;
}, "name" | "field" | "kind">>) | (Omit<{ ? */

which expands to
type TLabeldField = {
    placeholder?: string; required?: boolean; value?: string;
    block?: boolean;
    name?: string; field?: string; kind?: "string";
} | {
    placeholder?: string; required?: boolean; value?: string;
    name?: string; field?: string; kind?: "password";
} | {
    placeholder?: string; required?: boolean; value?: string;
    name?: string; field?: string; kind?: "email";
} | {
    placeholder?: string; required?: boolean; value?: number;
    name?: string; field?: string; kind?: "number";
} | {
    placeholder?: string; required?: boolean; value?: boolean;
    inline?: boolean;
    toggle?: boolean;
    name?: string; field?: string; kind?: "boolean";
} */

and thus your code now behaves as desired.
Playground link to code

is there a way to contact you more directly? Your answer here helped me understand some fundamental things with TypeScript and I'd like to discuss more.

I'd prefer not to interact outside of SO. I already spend a good deal of my free time here and I don't want that to spill over into my personal life. I'm not particularly hard to find, but generally I don't engage when people contact me via my personal/professional email address, phone, etc. Sorry!

I definitely understand the value of free time! Thanks for responding at all. I was hoping to get your input for another issue I'm having here but if/whenever you're available or interested. Thanks again
